# Defining the subtype of an object after it's created

Tags: java, c#, oop

Let's say I have following classes:

```
public class Animal {
  public string name;
  public int age;
  public bool canBark;
}

public class Dog : Animal {
  }
```

And instantiate an `Animal` like this:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
```

Is there anyway of downconverting this instance to a `Dog` instance after it's created? Or am I forced to recognize that my `Animal` is a `Dog` when I create it? The reason I'm having this problem is because my instance is created by calling a factory class that returns a type based on a JSON file that I feed it. The `canBark` attribute value is calculated by looking at several seemingly unrelated fields in that file. It seems it make more sense to determine that something is a `Dog` by looking at the `canBark` field, rather than those JSON fields.

```
public class AnimalFactory{
  public static Animal Create(JObject json){
    Animal a = new Animal();
    a.canBark = (json["someField"]["someOtherField"].ToString() == "abc")
    .....
}
```

I kind of solve this problem right now by having a constructor in the `Dog` class that takes an `Animal` as its argument and simply assigns the values of that instance's variables to its own. But this is not a very flexible way as I would need to add a line in each subclass constructor everytime I add a field.

So, is the best way of determining the type by moving that decision to the instance creation or is there some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway of downconverting this instance to a Dog instance after it's created?

No. The type of an object can never be changed after construction, in either Java or .NET. You'll need to change your factory code to create an instance of the right class. It's not immediately clear how the `canBark` part relates to the rest of the question, but fundamentally you need to have *somewhere* that decides what kind of object to create based on the JSON content - or change your design so it can use the same object type in all cases.

Comment: Followup question - could you write the classes so that `Dog fido = (Dog)myAnimal;` would work? I'm pretty sure you can't but I'm having a moment and can't pin down why.

Comment: If `myAnimal` is allocated as an `Animal`, you can't for two reasons: subclasses can be larger than base classes (but you allocated memory just for the base class) and the virtual table pointers are pointing to `Animal` functions, not `Dog` functions.

Comment: "or change your design to not need to use the same object type in all cases." Or change the code so that it always can use the same type in all cases.  If you handle the differences between different animals in some way other than polymorphism (which may or may not be appropriate depending on the specifics of the problem space) the whole problem goes away.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that was what I meant - I'm slightly woozy right now! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a factory method having an `Animal` return type but creating and returning a `Dog`. But you cannot convert an `Animal` to a `Dog` after its creation.

Note also that a true conversion and a type cast are not the same thing. Even if the cast operator is the same for both in C#. If you have a variable `Animal a = new Dog();`, then you can do the valid cast `Dog d = (Dog)a;`. But `a` must reference a `Dog` object. If it was assigned a `Cat`, the casting would throw an exception.

The best you can do, if you really want to convert an `Animal` to a `Dog`, is to add a constructor to `Dog` accepting an animal as argument (C#):

```
public Dog(Animal a)
{
    name = a.name;
    age = a.age;
    canBark = true;
}
```

Then you can create a dog with:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
// Initialize animal

Dog dog = new Dog(a);
```

But you cannot do it without creating a new object. Therefore, create the right type from the beginning in the factory:

```
public class AnimalFactory
{
    public static Animal Create(JObject json)
    {
        string animalType = Get animal type string from json;

        Animal a;
        switch (animalType) {
            case "dog":
                var dog = new Dog();
                // Fill dog specific stuff.
                a = dog;
                break;
            case "cat":
                var cat = new Cat();
                // Fill cat specific stuff.
                a = cat;
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        // Fill stuff common to all animals into a.
        return a;
    }
}
```

It also probably makes no sense to instantiate the `Animal` class directly. Therefore I would declare it as abstract.

---

You could also have constructors with a `JObject` parameter in the animal classes to delegate the initialization of the fields.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public Animal(JObject json)
    {
        // Initialize common fields.
    }

    public string name;
    public int age;
    public bool canBark;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(JObject json)
        : base(json) // Pass the json object to the Animal constructor
    {
        // Initialize dog specific fields.
    }
}
```

The factory then becomes

```
public class AnimalFactory
{
    public static Animal Create(JObject json)
    {
        string animalType = Get animal type string from json;
        switch (animalType) {
            case "dog":
                return new Dog(json);
            case "cat":
                return new Cat(json);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that you can't write a conversion from `Animal` to `Dog` - conversion operators can't convert from a base class to a derived class or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I've added a reference to the `explicit` operator and some more explanation.

Comment: I don't see it - you've still got "As it is explained here explicit (C# Reference), you could declare a user-defined type conversion" but that's just not true if `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`. You can't write a user-defined type conversion in that situation, so I don't think it's a good idea to even mention it.

Comment: Uhhh. I did not know about this restriction. I will reword it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

> Animal a = new Animal();

You should never do this at all, since in any non-academic environment, `Animal` is an abstract type.

> Is there anyway of downconverting this instance to a Dog instance after it's created?

It should be obvious, but `new` allocates memory. If you're telling it you're allocating memory for an `Animal`, but later decide it's actually a `Dog`, you can't add to the memory allocated.

In other words, you are what you are. If tomorrow you decide you want to be a monkey instead of (presumably) a human, you're not going to literally become a monkey.

Perhaps less obvious if you're not familiar at all with how virtual functions work is that the virtual table is initialized during `new`, so the compiler needs to know what function pointers to assign *at the point of creation*.

> a type based on a JSON file that I feed it

That's what dictionaries or dynamic objects (`ExpandoObject` in C#) are for. Or better yet, use proper libraries that handle this for you, like the infamous [Newtonsoft JSON library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Answer (score 0):

In languages like Java and C#, the type of an object is determined when it is created. You can declare an `Animal` reference and then point it at a `Dog`, but the `Dog` object itself will always be a `Dog`. The user of the object may not know its actual type, and it's usually better if it doesn't.

```
Animal a = new Dog();
a.onOwnerHome();
```

But you're onto something with your question. The fundamental problem with the `Animal` examples that you see so often in textbooks is that they tend to be very bad OOP. They model things that really should be data as behavior, and the student misses an opportunity to think about the kinds of things that *should* be modeled as behavior.